# converting time series into string

Tags: string, matlab, time-series

I want to convert time series data into strings, Is it possible?
As I search, there are some conversion from string to time series, not time series to string.
I would be so much thankful if you answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending with what kind of data you have to convert them into strings you can use

```
time = ('data_time.dat')
new_time_stamp=datestr(time,'yyyymmddHHMM'); %convert data of time into a string
```

With data_time the file that includes your data to be read

Although depending on the formation of you data, you should also look `datenum` as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply, suppose that I have a vector of data [1 2 3 6 3 2 7 8 1 0], and I want to convert it to string format. Not a date data.

Comment: @user2579230 then what about `num2str`?

Comment: @user2579230 yes that could work, but your question was on date conversion that is why i gave you the datestr